# Is it a coincidence that $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ has all distinct subgroups that are factors of 12?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

So I'm doing a problem where I need to find all the distinct subgroups of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ and I found them to be <1>, <2>, <3>, <4>, <6>, and <12>. They're all factors of 12 and was wondering if there's a theorem for this or something.

Comment: A subgroup of $\mathbb Z/12$ is the same as a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ containing $12$. Since $\mathbb Z$ is cyclic, this subgroup is generated by some $n\in\mathbb Z$, and so $12 \in n\mathbb Z$, that is, $n|12$.

Answer (score 2):

What you noted is an instance of a general fact about a finite cyclic group $G=\langle g\rangle$ of order say $n$.

It is a known fact that for every divisor $d$ of $n$ there is a unique subgroup of $G$ with $d$ elements, and that it is cyclic generated by $g^{n/d}$.

More over, every subgroup of $G$ is of this sort.

Answer (score 1):

Langrange's theorem tells us that the order of any subgroup of a (finite) group must be a divisor of the group's order.

Comment: we might also mention the fact that in every cyclic group of order $n$ there is exactly one subgroup of order $k$ for each divisor $k$ of $n$

Comment: Your answer, Henrik, is pretty far from the question, as OP is asking about the generators and you are writing about the order. OP might not be up to connecting the two.